# Windows 10 locks when gaming on 4K monitor

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, 4k-resolution, directx

I have an Asus ROG Laptop G752VT. Graphic card is NVidia GeForce GTX 970M. It comes with a Display Port, and everything works fine.

Recently I bought an LG 4K monitor (3840 x 2160 @60Hz), I connected it to the laptop via de Display Port. If I try to play a game using either DirectX 11 or DirectX 12, the games starts normally, full screen and everything. I even manage to play for few minutes, then the screen goes to a Windows "Blocked" full screen message, and the PC shuts down. Looks like some kind of "protection", because the PC goes to hybernation mode. If I start up the PC again, it will return to my previous desktop, including the game I was playing.

Do you have any idea of what could be causing the problem?

I have updated the video card driver, changed resolution (the monitor complains that it's not its optimal resolution) but works, I've been looking on the internet for similar issues but found none. It doesn't matter where the game comes from: stand alone, Steam, or any other thing.

Comment: I found this info on the Web. "Even higher-performance models, like the GeForce GTX 970M, are pushed to their limits while running the latest games at 4k. Overall, we can say that the GeForce GTX 980M is the only notebook GPU capable of handling the high performance requirements of 4k gaming."

Comment:  sad... so far the only game I have been able to play at 4K is Civilization VI, anything else, locks after few minutes. Thanks!